# React Native - JSON value '1311' of type NSNumber cannot be converted to NSDictionary

Tags: json, xcode, react-native

I'm building react native app using gelocation and react native maps, but i'm getting error on XCode simulator that says

> JSON value '1311' of type NSNumber cannot be converted to NSDictionary

but it's just working fine on android simulator anyone know how to fix this? Thanks.

Here is my code

```js
Geolocation.setRNConfiguration(info => console.log(info));
navigator.geolocation = require('@react-native-community/geolocation');

const {width, height} = Dimensions.get('window')

const SCREEN_HEIGHT = height
const SCREEN_WIDTH = width
const ASPECT_RATIO = width / height
const LATITUDE_DELTA = 0.0922
const LONGITUDE_DELTA = LATITUDE_DELTA * ASPECT_RATIO

class mapView extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      initialPosition: {
        latitude: 0,
        longitude: 0,
        latitudeDelta: 0,
        longitudeDelta: 0,
      },
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
      var lat = parseFloat(position.coords.latitude)
      var long = parseFloat(position.coords.longitude)

      var initialRegion = {
        latitude: lat,
        longitude: long,
        latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
        longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA,
      }

      this.setState({initialPosition: initialRegion})
    },
    (error) => alert(JSON.stringify(error)),
    {enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000});
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <MapView
            showsUserLocation={true}
            provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
            style={styles.map}
            initialRegion={this.state.initialPosition}/>
            <TouchableOpacity style={{top: 100, left: 20}}>
              <Text>test</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    );
  }
}
```

[image: error message]